# SQLite 3 substract in update query gives near "–": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to execute update query with subtraction inside:

```
UPDATE categories_ns
SET
 nsright = nsright – 10
WHERE
    nsright > 9
```

And I am getting [Err] 1 - near "–": syntax error.

Could you please help me to understand why its happens ?

Thanks!

Comment: `–` is not `-` by the way. Is that what your database actually ouputs, copy-pasted without intermediaries?

Comment: @D-side Yep (. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for what? Did that actually resolve your problem or that's just "yes" to my question?

Comment: @D-side This is Yes to you question and this resolve my problem )

Comment: Alright, I "answerized" my first comment with some hints on how to detect and avoid that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And yet again someone is having issues with Unicode having so many similar symbols and some of them getting into code by accident.

`–` and `-` are different symbols. The former is not a valid minus, the latter is.

The difference in dashes' lengths is often unclear in many monospaced fonts. You can view your code in a non-monospaced one so the difference becomes obvious. But first and foremost, avoid copying code that may not be what it looks like.

Some document processors and websites out there, for instance:

- Replace quotes with fancier ones (like `˝`)
- Replace `<<` and `>>` with `«` and `»`
- Replace a "minus" constructs like `-` with a proper dash (`–`, `—`?)

...all of which make sense for prose or poems, but not code.